# Rails: STI and order of arguments in an 'includes' statement breaking my query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Given `User`, `Professional`, and `Event`,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
end

class Professional < User
  # Table name 'Users'
  has_many :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :professional
end
```

and using [ActiveAdmin](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin), I have an Events index page. ActiveAdmin uses [meta_search](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/meta_search) to create filters, and I've got an `email_starts_with` filter to filter the Event records by a user's email address. Originally, the collection it was dealing with was defined as:

```
def scoped_collection
  Event.includes(:user, :professional)
end
```

At some point, the order got changed to:

```
Event.includes(:professional, :user)
```

and the filter blew everything up: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'users_event.id' ...`

I'm assuming this is related to the fact that both users and professionals are stored in the same table (this is a simplified version; the real one has more arguments in the `includes` statement, and only the order of `:user` and `:professional` seem to matter), but I'm not clear on what precisely is happening here.

Comment: Could it be the fact that your specifying `has_many :events` on both User and Professional, even though Professional inherits from User?  I think you'd just need/want it on User.